# Error: You must return a Promise in your transaction()-callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, es6-promise, google-cloud-firestore

My script is throwing the following error when returning the result of the assync firestore set function:

> You must return a Promise in your transaction()-callback.

According to firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#set) about transactions, set function return a transaction itself.

Here a simplified copy of my code.

```
var myDoc = {
  field1: "v1"
};
var docRef = db
  .collection("docs")
  .doc("1");

return db
  .runTransaction(t => {
    return t
      .set(docRef, chat, {merge:false}); //has i understand, this should return a transaction object but the error says otherwise.
  })
  .then( doc => {
    response.send();
  })
  .catch(err => {
  ...;
  })
```

I am still new to Nodejs and not very familiar with chaining assyncs methods, so i must be doing some obvious error here.

Comment: It's probably in regard of `return t`, I am not familiar with `.runTransaction` but you can try to replace `return t` with `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { t.set(...); resolve(); });`

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used firestore transaction but I have used firebase transactions. You can try following

```
return db
  .runTransaction(t => {
    return t.set(docRef, chat, {merge:false})
      .then(data => {
        return Promise.resolve('transaction complete');       
      })
      .then( doc => {
        response.send();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        ...;
      })
```

and the method that encloses your whole code must be returning promise as you have written `return db.runTransaction(t => {....})`
so if that is not needed then use

`var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {...});`

Comment: It does eliminate the error but don't seam to wait for set results, if i understand it correctly.

Comment: updated answer try that but this should not happen will try this later.

Comment: With the update i got  the error :TypeError: t.set(...).then is not a function
It appears that set doesn't return a promise. If i debug into the set function, i see it returns this, the transaction. The error is confusing. My guess is that i don't need to chain the responses inside a transaction, just pass several callbacks to the transaction and the server will run then one after other.

Comment: You need a transaction when the document you are about to set(), might change during this process. So a typical transaction would start with a get() which returns a promise where you can attach ur set-operations to.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
return db
  .runTransaction(t => {
      t.set(docRef, chat, {merge:false}); 
      return Promise.resolve(); // Add this line.
  })
  .then( doc => {
     response.send();
  })
  .catch(err => {
     ...;
  })
```

If the `t.set()` failed, it won't go to the `resolve()` anyway.